# Unsatisfied Dependency Exception | Error creating bean

Tags: spring-boot, exception, service, controller, dependencies

I am working on a Crud operation spring boot application using Mongodb. I'm not able to figure out what is causing this error message. Whether it's the annotations or some extra code that I should add.

Exception/Error message:

Error creating bean with name 'movieController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service': Error creating bean with name 'movieService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository': Error creating bean with name 'movieRepository' defined in dev.farhan.movieist.movies.MovieRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'

Below are the service, controller, Repository, Movie, application snippets.

[@Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxSPt.png)

[@Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQwlw.png)

[@Repository (Ignore the @Service)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhZKQ.png)

[Movie Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4pQD.png)

[Spring Boot application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NU6s.png)